# Py2exe [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'm'

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I'm trying to use py2exe to create a simple exe using py2exe. Unfortunately, when I try to create even a simple py2exe, it fails.

My Python script is:

```
print("Hello World")
```

My setup script is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console="mouse-check.py")
```

When I run `py py2exe-installer.py py2exe` I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\...\Python\py2exe-installer.py:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.core import setup
running py2exe
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'm'
```

I'm using `Python 3.10.4` on Windows.

My py2exe version is: `0.11.1.1`

My directory structure is:

```
/Python
- py2exe-installer.py
- mouse-check.py
```

Anyone have any idea what "m" is referring to here?

Comment: The `console` argument needs to be a list.

Comment: Well then. That would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setup` function requires `console` argument is **list**, you can read more details in [the implementation](https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/blob/6e4a70a049556742c1c0a8be2ee90f80f9f6a854/py2exe/setup_template.py#L162). Or tutorial and examples [here](https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial).

Your setup script should be looked like this

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=["mouse-check.py"])
```